# Dynamic generation of routes base on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like my route name to be based on a stored json on my database.
For example:
Product table in my database contains the json:

```
"tv screen 12:" {"title": "one", "content": "two"}
"toaster 3:" {"title": "two", "content": "two}
}
```

In my rails application I have link_to, or ng-href links which currently redirect to the route:

```
http://localhost:3000/product?generic_product_key=%D7%9E%
```

now the customer asked for the following thing:
Instead of this route the route should be

```
'localhost:3000/tv_screen_12'
```

in case of the user clicks on toaster link, `localhost:3000/toaster_3'` these routes are based on the json value from the project database. my questions are 1. How to do this and make the routes be dynamic and based on the json keys. and second - Could my current ProductController handle these different routes ? (does not make sense to me)

Comment: have you tried using friendly_id http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/

Comment: It seems like this friendly id could maybe change the url path odlf the browser. It does not solve my core problem - if the route is dynamic and can be created from some db data field (assuming friendly id could do that), which controller will handle the route request ?

Comment: You can do this with a catch-all route `get "*product" => "products#show"` - however you need to declare this at the very top of your routes file or it will clobber every other route that matches the pattern (like `/foo` and `/bar`). However I would question if this is actually a good idea - catch-all's are a good way to shoot yourself in the foot. I would rethink and use a simpler approach with either ids or slugs in a proper RESTful pattern.

Comment: You could do `http://localhost:3000/product?generic_product_key=%D7%9E%` by creating a `get '/products', to: 'products#show'` route with a [constraint](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) that requires the `generic_product_key` param to be present. This needs to have a higher precedence than the regular index route. But again - its overcomplicated and not worth it.

Comment: First of all - thank you very much for this useful information. A question - why do you consider the catch-all route solution to be bad solution ? what bad can come form it ? (it is a product - not a freelance project. so it is important that no crazy side effects will appear). And - can you give a working example of solution 2? Also I think you mean to put the catch-all route in the bottom not in top